# Jquery: Call function on drop down menu selection.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created and populated a drop down, I wish to alert(1) when the option in the dropdown changes. I can do it for a button with onclick but onchange doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.

global.js file:

```
$('input#lst_MonthDrop').on('change',function(){
    alert(1);                                                                                      
};
```

Drop down menu:

```
<select name="lst_MonthDrop" style="background-color:#FF9933; color:#FFF; border:none; margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;" onchange="global.js">
      <option>Please Select</option>
           <?php 
            include 'populatedrodown.php';
            foreach ( $results as $option ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option->Date; ?>"><?php echo $option->Date; ?>     </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: As pointed out in one of the answers below, lose the `onchange="global.js"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `onchange` attribute you currently have, and also target the elements `name` attribute. You do not have an ID:

```
$("select[name=lst_MonthDrop]").change(function() {
```

Comment: All the answers are good but I like this one most because it points out the onchange in the tag.  Not needed when using jquery :-)

Answer (score 0):

`#lst_MonthDrop` is `<select>` not `<input>`

Change

```
$('input#lst_MonthDrop').on('change',function(){
    alert(1);                                                                                      
};
```

to

```
$('select[name="lst_MonthDrop"]').on('change',function(){
    alert(1);                                                                                      
};
```